Utilize Langchain for RAG + General Knowledge
I am trying to create a chatbot that takes past social media posts (only text) of users and is capable of generating new posts based on that. However, my ideal scenario here would be to use RAG but also leverage the inherent capabilities of an LLM. In my case, if I ask my chatbot, "What is the height of Mount Everest?", it replies that it does not know. However, it is able to answer questions related to the previous posts stored in Chromadb.
What might be an optimum approach to follow here? The following is my code so far. I am using ConversationalRetrievalChain at the moment.
import os
import streamlit as st
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain_google_genai import ChatGoogleGenerativeAI
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain_google_genai import GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.schema import HumanMessage, AIMessage

# Load environment variables
load_dotenv()

# Google API Key
GOOGLE_API_KEY = os.getenv("GOOGLE_API_KEY")

# Initialize the LLM with Google Generative AI
llm = ChatGoogleGenerativeAI(
    model="gemini-1.5-pro",
    google_api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY
)

if 'user_id' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['user_id'] = ''

# Create a text input for the user ID and link it to session_state using the 'key' parameter
st.text_input("Enter your user ID (e.g., user_1):", key='user_id')

# Check if the user_id has been entered
if not st.session_state['user_id']:
    st.warning("User ID is required!")
    st.stop()  # Stop the execution until a valid user_id is provided

# Once user_id is provided, you can proceed with the rest of your app
st.success(f"Welcome, {st.session_state['user_id']}!")

# Load the embeddings model
embeddings_model = GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings(model='models/embedding-001')

# Define the directory and collection name
chroma_persist_directory = "chroma_db"
collection_name = "user_posts_collection"

# Load the existing Chroma vector store
vectorstore = Chroma(
    embedding_function=embeddings_model,
    persist_directory=chroma_persist_directory,
    collection_name=collection_name
)



# Create a retriever that filters by user_id
def get_user_retriever(user_id):
    retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(
        search_type="similarity",
        search_kwargs={
            "k": 5,  # Number of documents to retrieve
            "filter": {"user_id": {"$eq": user_id}}  # Filter by user_id
        }
    )
    return retriever

# Get the retriever for the current user


user_retriever = get_user_retriever(st.session_state['user_id'])

# Initialize or retrieve the memory from session state with explicit output_key
if 'memory' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
        memory_key="chat_history",
        return_messages=True,
        output_key='answer'  # Specify which key to use as output
    )

# Create the ConversationalRetrievalChain with return_source_documents=True
qa_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm=llm,
    retriever=user_retriever,
    memory=st.session_state.memory,
    verbose=True,
    return_source_documents=True  # Enable returning source documents
)

# Streamlit App Interface
st.title("AGP Chatbot")

# Display the conversation history
for message in st.session_state.memory.chat_memory.messages:
    if isinstance(message, HumanMessage):
        with st.chat_message("user"):
            st.markdown(message.content)
    elif isinstance(message, AIMessage):
        with st.chat_message("assistant"):
            st.markdown(message.content)

# Input field for the user message
if user_input := st.chat_input("Type your message here..."):
    # Display the user's message
    with st.chat_message("user"):
        st.markdown(user_input)

    # Run the ConversationalRetrievalChain
    response = qa_chain({"question": user_input})

    # Extract the answer and source documents from the response
    answer = response.get('answer', "I'm sorry, I couldn't find an answer to that.")
    source_documents = response.get('source_documents', [])

    # Display the assistant's response
    with st.chat_message("assistant"):
        st.markdown(answer)

    # Optionally, display all retrieved posts (source documents)
    if source_documents:
        st.markdown("**Retrieved Posts:**")
        for idx, doc in enumerate(source_documents, start=1):
            with st.expander(f"Post {idx}"):
                st.markdown(f"**Content:** {doc.page_content}")
                st.markdown(f"**Metadata:** {doc.metadata}")

